# the value of a variable or expression of type array is the address of element zero of the array

Tags: arrays

I'm reading K&R programming language 2ed.
In section 5.3(page 99):

> By definition, the value of a variable or expression of type array is the address of element zero of the array.

It tells us that if I declare an array:

```
int arr[3];
```

The value of arr is a default value of address of the first element of array.

I tried to set a experiment in gcc that:

```
int arr[3] = {0, 1, 2};
printf("%p",arr);
```

The output is still the address of the first element of array, although I've changed it to 0.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the variable `arr` is a pointer itself having the address to the first element of `{0, 1, 2}`

It would be equivalent to do this:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 1;
int c = 2;

printf("%p", &a);
```

The `%p` prints the address a pointer is pointing too. (I know, it sounds confusing)

Comment: Is the variable arr a pointer which is pointing to the start address of an array, or the variable arr is itself an array?

Comment: The variable `arr` is an actual pointer, under the hood the compiler is telling the computer to reserve 3 memory segments that can hold one integer each, then creates the `arr` variable and stores the address of the first segment of that memory space in it.

Comment: Thank you. If that is the case, the address of "pointer variable arr" must be different than the address of that first segment. But the true is that the address of arr is the same as the address of that first segment which is pointed to by arr. Why?

Comment: What I mean is: &arr = &arr[0]. Which should be different

Answer (score 1):

The `printf` specifier `%p` will print the actual memory address of `arr`, which contains the value of the first element of the array.

The following code will dereference the pointer and print the value contained in the memory locaction pointed to by arr.

```
printf("%u\n", *arr);
```

The syntax:

```
printf("%u\n", arr[0]);
```

Will also dereference the array pointer, if that is what you are interested in.